# Numeric overflow in insert query

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I am receiving an error of:

> Arithmetic overflow or division by zero has occurred. arithmetic
>   exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation. numeric value is
>   out of range.

This can be replicated with:

```
create table testing (avalue numeric(3,2));
```

and the following insert:

```
insert into testing values (328);
```

However, using the following works fine:

```
insert into testing values (327);
```

328 seems to be the magic figure the error occurs.  To me, the `numeric(3,2)` declaration should allow me 000-999 with 2 decimal places but based on the above that is wrong.

Can someone explain why this is and what I should declare my domain as if I want to allow 0-999 with 2 decimal places as.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

328 is not "magic" number :)
The magic number is 32767 ( 0x7FFF). This is `SMALLINT` type limit.

*Note : Firebird not support unsigned integer type.*

Limit for `NUMERIC` type vary according to storage type and scale.
Internal storage type are `SMALLINT`, `INTEGER` and `BIGINT` according by precision as:

precision-type

1..4 - SMALLINT

5..9 - INTEGER

10..18 - BIGINT

So

`NUMERIC(3,2)` is `SMALLINT` internal type max 32767 / 100 = 327.67.

**Update**

[Firebird 2.5 Language Reference](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/firebird-russian-documentation/documents/bUASAykFqr5l_dacwqjQWU/download/bUASAykFqr5l_dacwqjQWU)
by
Paul Vinkenoog,
Dmitry Yemanov and 
Thomas Woinke

contains more comprehensive description of `NUMERIC` type than other official Firebird documents.

> NUMERIC (precision, scale) is the exact number with the decimal
>   precision and scale specified by the  and .
>
> **Syntax:** 
>        NUMERIC [precision [, scale]]
>
> The scale of NUMERIC is the count of decimal digits in the
>   fractional part, to the right of the decimal point. The precision of
>   NUMERIC is the total count of decimal digits in the number.
>
> The precision must be positive, the maximum supported value is 18.
>   The scale must be zero or positive, up to the specified precision.
>
> If  the  scale  is  omitted,  then  zero  value  is  implied,  thus 
>   meaning  an  integer  value  of  the  specified precision, i.e.
>   NUMERIC (P) is equivalent to NUMERIC (P, 0). If both the precision and
>   the scale are omitted, then precision of 9 and zero scale are implied,
>   i.e. NUMERIC is equivalent to NUMERIC (9, 0).
>
> The internal representation of the NUMERIC data type may vary.
>   Numerics with the precision up to (and including) 4 are always stored
>   as scaled short integers (SMALLINT). Numerics with the precision up to
>   (and including) 9 are always stored as scaled regular integers
>   (INTEGER). Storage of higher precision numerics depends on the SQL
>   dialect. In Dialect 3, they are stored as scaled large integers
>   (BIGINT). In Dialect 1, however, large integers are not available,
>   therefore they are stored as double precision floating-point values
>   (DOUBLE PRECISION).
>
> The effective precision limit for the given value depends on the
>   corresponding storage. For example, NUMERIC (5) will be stored as
>   INTEGER, thus allowing values in the precision range up to (and
>   including) NUMERIC (9). **So beware that the declared precision is not
>   strictly enforced**.
>
> Values outside the range limited by the effective precision are not
>   allowed. Values with the scale larger than the declared one will be
>   rounded to the declared scale while performing an assignment.

Comment: But the [Firebird docs, datatypes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql-data-types.html) state: *"A subtle difference in the way NUMERIC and DECIMAL behave in Firebird to bear in mind is that the **NUMERIC definition means exactly the precision requested** (total number of digits), while **DECIMAL mean at least the request precision** (the digits to the right of the decimal symbol, however, are maintained exactly). In MS SQL, on the other hand, numeric and decimal are synonims."* Why then `numeric(3,2)` allows `327` to be inserted?

Comment: @ypercube http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq61/  Numeric and Decimal are internally stored as smallint, integer or bigint depending on the size. They can handle up to 18 digits.  http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/  Numeric Size 16, 32 or 64 bits. Numeric(3, 2) is `smallint`because it is `ppp,ss` Smalint is 0xFFF (32767)  and Numeric(3,2) allows 327,67 to be inserted. I think in my response I have explained well.

Comment: You have explained it well, But it would be much better if you added the links to the documentation (because some of the official Firebird docs are contradicting). The second link you posted for example has *"Example: Numeric(10,3) holds numbers accurately in the following format: ppppppp.sss"*. So a Numeric(3,2) should be storing from -9.99 to 9.99 (and not allow 327.67)

Comment: @ypercube   I understood. I do not remember exactly where I read it. I will seek and will post it tomorrow. Ok?

Comment: @ypercube Thank you for your note. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `numeric(5, 2)` gives you numbers from 0.00 to 999.99.  The declaration `numeric(3,2)` gives you numbers from 0.00 to 9.99.  This is sort-of illustrated [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/).  But these are the standard declarations for numerics in SQL.

The "3" is the scale, which is the total number of digits in the number, not the number to the left of the decimal place.

I'm not sure why 327 is allowed.

Comment: The Firebird behavior of `NUMERIC` is more like the SQL-standard `DECIMAL` in that it allows a precision larger than the defined precision. The major difference in Firebird between `NUMERIC` and `DECIMAL` is that the first is backed by `smallint` (1-4), `integer` (5-9) or `bigint` (10-18), while the second by `integer`(1-9) and `bigint` (10-18), both have behaviour at the extremes of the backing datatype (see the other answer below) which you might not expect.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel is that somewhere documented?